# How can I get those code to only return once?

Tags: python, string

"Assume s is a string of lower case characters.

Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print"

So far this is my code.

```
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+3] == "bob":
        count += 1
  print("Number of times bob occurs is: " + str(count))
```

However, I keep getting:

Number of times bob occurs is: 0
Number of times bob occurs is: 0
Number of times bob occurs is: 0
Number of times bob occurs is: 1
Number of times bob occurs is: 1
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
Number of times bob occurs is: 2

I am trying to make it where it only returns or prints 2.

Comment: The code you show only prints once. There's nothing visibly wrong with it. You're clearly missing something here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. If you ident very well, the answer should be Number of times bob occurs is: 2.

Comment: Your question is missing a number in it, and the handling of overlaps is not addressed explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation seems off. Not here in the post but maybe in the real code. I tried your program and the output was printed only once. The print statement should be outside the loop i.e. at the same indentation level.

Comment: This was the issue, I figured it was something I was missing.